# Переход с MySQL на MySQLi

Tags: apache, mysqli, php, mysql

Где можно менять тип используемого модуля `SQL`?
Нужно сменить с `MySQL` на `MySQLi`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А почему не [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php)?
И модуль не меняется. Обычно mysqli уже установлен.
Кстати вы [мануал](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.installation.php) читать не пробовали?

**UPDATE**
Если всё уже установлено, то вам остаётся поменять код.

Comment: Проблема в том, что мне надо сменить его на хостинге. В myphpadmin сказано, что уже стоит mysql

Comment: если есть доступ к консоли серверы, вполните команду "php -m | grep mysql" и сразу узнаете какие модули для mysql уже установлены. И если стоит то что нужно, то меняйте свой код.
P.s. тег apache лишний